# Device to Device(s) real time communication - Best practice?

Tags: java, android, communication

In our scenario are a lot of android smartphones involved.
You can "subscribe" to a survey group and doing some stuff there... The creator are able to change something (via Android APP or desktop application, for example start a new survey) and the subscribed android clients should get the changed stuff immediately (view the started survey and answer it).

So my question is the following:
How it is possible to update the user data immediately on all subscribed clients in real-time?

Is it possible to realize it with the C2DM Framework (with a highest delay of 30secods)?

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: one thing I can tell you. C2DM is not made for this kind of real-time communication.

Comment: Ok thanks, it's just for push notifications right?

Comment: push notifications are about the only way you can communicate with apps without the app querying a server. unless the app connects to a socket and holds the connection open for your server to push data out. push is your best bet. and while it's not "real-time", for most users it will be with a minute or two. 

and it isn't called C2DM anymore, it's GCM